# How to deploy multiple database on Team build

Tags: msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I tried the following in MSBuild Arguments but this didn't work out.

```
/t:Build;Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=McMData1.local.publish.xml 
/p:SqlPublishProfilePath McMData1.local.publish.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only specify one SqlPublishProfilePath value. You can create another msbuild command task to publish another database project separately or create another build definition.

Also, you could make the [database properties inside the xml file command line driven](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-ssdt-projects-with-tfs-build.aspx) , but you can still only specify one .xml file and have one deployment.